# Flood extent extraction from satellite images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, image, classification, modis

How can I extract the floodwater from satellite images? Is the image classification method accurate for moderate-resolution satellite (Terra/Aqua MODIS)? Or are there more accurate methods?

Comment: Aerial Photography will give you more resolution and more accurate results (with ground control points). What is the Satellite Imagery Resolution?

Comment: 250 metres [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderate-Resolution_Imaging_Spectroradiometer)

Comment: In the UK Insurance industry the accuracy needs to be +/-10 meters. So that 1:15, 1:25, 1:50 & 1:100 year flood plains can be modeled. Also based on historical facts/extents

Comment: We need in Southest Asia create extent of floodwater not floodplain. [Southest Asia floods 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Southeast_Asian_floods)

Comment: Data imagery in real-time [lance](http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?project=&subset=FAS_Indochina&date=11%2F02%2F2011)

Comment: depends of the area of interest, per example last year i tried to find the flooded area in bare soil, but the classification has a lot of problems because everything was classify as water. If your area of interest have vegetation perhaps the water is beneath the forest. i recommend you use radar data (per example sentinel-1)